# SQL (Sybase) Return SUM of calculated rows

Tags: sql, sybase

The following query returns all the customers that have a credit balance (Columns ID and Total) - is there any way to return just the sum of Total?

```
SELECT Customer_ID AS 'ID',
  (
    SELECT SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit)
    FROM A_Sales_Ledger
    WHERE Document_Date <= '2013-09-30'
      AND Customer_ID = ID
  ) AS 'Total'
FROM A_Sales_Ledger
WHERE Total > 0
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(a.total)
FROM (
  SELECT (SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit)) AS "total"
  FROM A_Sales_Ledger
  WHERE Document_Date <= '2013-09-30'
  GROUP BY Customer_ID
  HAVING SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit) > 0
  ) a;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24564/5)</kbd>

Comment: Hey Filipe - Thanks for your response but that just does the same thing - returns all the rows for each customer - I'm trying to get the sum of all the returned rows :-)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understood that when i read the question.. I updated my answer and fiddle

Comment: @gchq. The fiddle is for mysql, since there isn't sybase to choose, but i think it will work the same way.

Comment: Thank you Filipe - that did the job - never used 'having' before so that will go into the ol' bag of tricks :-)